# Subset Sum recursive Java

Tags: java, recursion, sum, subset

I'm sorry for being dumb, but can you please explain the last recursive lines to me in plain English:

```
public static void find(int[] A, int currSum, int index, int sum,
        int[] solution) {
    if (currSum == sum) {
        System.out.println("\nSum found");
        for (int i = 0; i < solution.length; i++) {
            if (solution[i] == 1) {
                System.out.print("  " + A[i]);
            }
        }

    } else if (index == A.length) {
        return;
    } else {
        solution[index] = 1;// select the element
        currSum += A[index];
        find(A, currSum, index + 1, sum, solution);
        currSum -= A[index];    
        solution[index] = 0;// do not select the element
        find(A, currSum, index + 1, sum, solution);
    }
    return;
}
```

From what I understand the first recursion adds up all the numbers up to 13. After it marks the last index (4 in this case) as 0 and it substracts it from the sum.

After that it's pretty foggy for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post code and not links to code. See : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm sorry for that, I was just anxious to find out the answer. Again sorry for the missunderstanding

Comment: Some information is missing from the question : "adds up all the numbers up to 13"  - where do you see 13 ?  "it marks the last index (4 in this case)"  - again, what is 4 based upon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we will look at this example: `A = [1,2,3], sum = 3`:

- The first recursion will find that index 0 and 1 will sum up to 3. So they will be printed. This recursion will continue to another recursion, but curSum will be 3, so we will return from it. `currSum -= A[index]` will reduce 2 from currSum (because A[1] = 2). The reason for that is that you want to check the first element (zero indexed) with the third element (maybe both of them, without the second, can sum up to 3). You are doing also `solution[index] = 0` because you want to ignore A[1] from the printing. The last thing is the 'second' recursion in the code (but not in order of execution) `find(A, 1, 1 + 1, 3, solution);` and it continues with this logic.

Try to do it on a simple, small and relevant example. Exact like my example here. Write it on paper and "enter" by yourself to all the recursions there. Draw it like a tree and go up in the tree every time you see a return statement.

Hope it will help you (It will also convince you why there is so much work there that you can eliminate by using dynamic programming).

Comment: Thank you so much for writing that down! I will try to do it as you told me.

Have a good one!

Comment: @minihulk22 great! Feel free to ask more questions.